# Autostart VM on Witsbits (ClearVM) Server

Tags: virtualization

I am setting up few VMs on my Witsbits (ClearVM) server.

They are easy to setup and manage but... I would like to start VM together with the server.

The management interface allows for manual startup only. I cannot find how to do it from a script level.

So, How to autostart the VM on the Witbits virtualization platform?